# It is possible to prevent a page load using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, query-string, pageload

I am trying to use javascript to return a query parameter to a client that posted the query.  I capture the query parameter and then perform a document.write(parameter) command.  However, the client is receiving back both the document.write data and also the HTML page content which renders the callback invalid as the client only expects back the parameter.  So how can I prevent from sending back the web page contents after I perform the document.write so I only return the parameter value instead?

Below is my javascript.  The web page is created as an .aspx file.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//      function returnCallback() {
        var parm = location.search;

        var qs=parm.split("&");

        for (var i=0; i < qs.length; i++)
        {

                var pos = qs[i].indexOf('challenge');
                if (pos > -1) {
                    var qsarray = qs[i].split("=");
                    var challenge = qsarray[1];
                    document.write(challenge);

            }
        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<textarea id="text1" cols="80" rows="20"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `return false;` statement

Comment: I tried to use return false but it will not let me do a return unless it is inside of a function which in this case there is no function.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance I can see nothing wrong with your code, I am assuming the problem lies with the page you are calling, it should only return the needed data as you are just capturing what it throws.

Comment: I used an example straight from the instagram page which tells how to respond to a request for a subscription which I am trying to do.  There sample is http://your-callback.com/url/?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=15f7d1a91c1f40f8a748fd134752feb3&hub.verify_token=myVerifyToken.  If I substitute my webpage as the callback it returns the hub.challenge just like I want to but if I submit this request through my PHP program that requests the subscription through a curl command I get an error that says it received back the whole page rather than just my query parameter.